# How to blink an LED on ARM STR9

Tags: microcontroller, c

I am quite new to STR 9 and also to micro controller programming.
Can anyone please explain the meaning of these lines in the example blinky. I am having trouble in understanding it. Thanks

I want to blink just one LED at a time, say led nr 4 . How can i do it?

```
    int main (void) {
  unsigned int i, n;
  unsigned short AD_old, AD_value;

  /* ADC Setup                                                                */
  SCU->GPIOIN[4]  |= 0x01;                /* P4.0 input  - mode 0             */
  SCU->GPIOOUT[4] &= 0xFFFC;              /* P4.0 output - mode 0             */
  GPIO4->DDR      &= 0xFE;                /* P4.0 direction - input           */
  SCU->GPIOANA    |= 0x0001;              /* P4.0 analog mode ON              */

  ADC->CR         |= 0x0002;              /* Set POR bit                      */
  for (n = 0; n < 100000; n ++);          /* Wait > 1 ms  (at 96 MHz)         */

  ADC->CR         &= 0xFFF7;              /* Clear STB bit                    */
  for (n = 0; n < 1500; n ++);            /* Wait > 15 us (at 96 MHz)         */

  ADC->CR         |= 0x0400;              /* Enable end of conversion interupt*/
  ADC->CCR         = 0x0003;              /* AD Conversion, No WDG on Ch 0    */

  SCU->GPIOOUT[7]  = 0x5555;              /* P7.0..7 output - mode 1          */
  GPIO7->DDR       = 0xFF;                /* P7.0..7 Outputs (LED Data)       */

  /* LCD Setup                                                                */
  GPIO8->DDR       = 0xFF;                /* P8.0..7 Outputs (LCD Data)       */
  GPIO9->DDR       = 0x07;                /* P9.0..2 Outputs (LCD Control)    */

  lcd_init();
  lcd_clear();
  lcd_print (" MCB-LAB  ");
  set_cursor (0, 1);
  lcd_print (" biomed ");

  for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) wait();       /* Wait for initial display         */

  /* Configure and enable IRQ for A/D Converter (ADC)                         */
  VIC0->VAiR[15]  = (unsigned int)ADC_IRQ_Handler; /* Setup ADC IRQ Hndl addr */
  VIC0->VCiR[15] |= 0x20;                 /* Enable the vector interrupt      */
  VIC0->VCiR[15] |= 15;                   /* Specify the interrupt number     */
  VIC0->INTER    |= (1<<15);              /* Enable ADC interrupt             */

  /* Configure and enable IRQ for Timer (TIM3)                                */
  VIC0->VAiR[7]   = (unsigned int)TIM3_IRQ_Handler;/* Setup TIM3 IRQ Hndl addr*/
  VIC0->VCiR[7]  |= 0x20;                 /* Enable the vector interrupt      */
  VIC0->VCiR[7]  |= 7;                    /* Specify the interrupt number     */
  VIC0->INTER    |= (1<<7);               /* Enable TIM3 interrupt            */

  /* Timer 3 Configuration (TIM3)                                             */
  TIM3->CNTR      = 0x0000;               /* Setup TIM3 counter register      */
  TIM3->CR2      &= 0xFF00;               /* Clear prescaler value            */
  TIM3->CR2      |= 0x000F;               /* Setup TIM3 prescaler             */
  TIM3->CR2      |= 0x2000;               /* TIM3 timer overflow intrupt en   */
  TIM3->CR1      |= 0x8000;               /* TIM3 counter enable              */

    while (1) {                             /* Loop forever                     */
    for (n = 0x01; n <= 0xFF; n <<= 1) {
      GPIO7->DR[0x3FC] = n;               /* Turn on LED                      */
      wait();                             /* Delay                            */
      AD_value = AD_last;                 /* Read AD_last value               */
      if (AD_value != AD_last)            /* Make sure that AD interrupt did  */
        AD_value = AD_last;               /* not interfere with value reading */
      AD_value /= 13;                     /* Scale to AD_Value to 0 - 78      */
      if (AD_old != AD_value)  {          /* If AD value has changed          */
        set_cursor (0, 1);
        AD_old = AD_value;
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)  {       /* Disp bargraph according to AD    */
          if (AD_value > 5)  {
            lcd_putchar (0x05);
            AD_value -= 5;
          }  else  {
            lcd_putchar (AD_value);
            AD_value = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The first thing is to remove all of the stuff unrelated to flashing the LED.

```
int main (void) {

  SCU->GPIOOUT[7]  = 0x5555;              /* P7.0..7 output - mode 1          */
  GPIO7->DDR       = 0xFF;                /* P7.0..7 Outputs (LED Data)       */

    while (1) {                             /* Loop forever                     */
    for (n = 0x01; n <= 0xFF; n <<= 1) {  
      GPIO7->DR[0x3FC] = n;               /* Turn on LED                      */
  }
}
```

I haven't looked at the datasheet, but I would guess that:

`SCU->GPIOOUT` sets the function of the pins to GPIO.
`GPIO7->DDR` sets the pins to outputs (Data Direction Register)
`GPIO7->DR` sets the data to be output.

The next step is to look at those registers in the documentation and check their exact function.

Comment: +1 for `The first thing is to remove all of the stuff unrelated to flashing the LED.`

Comment: Another +1 for removing all of the stuff unrelated to flashing the LED.

Answer (score 4):

The STR91x family of microcontrollers has very flexible peripherals. Unfortunately, this flexibility makes them somewhat complicated to set up. My suggestion is to start by downloading the STR91xFA Firmware Library from [ST.com](http://www.st.com/internet/mcu/product/165891.jsp). Once you have the library linked into your project, you need to do something similar to the following to configure port 7 (assuming your LEDs are attached to port 7) as general purpose output pins:

```
void InitGPIO7( void )
{
   GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

   /* Enable the GPIO7 clock */
   SCU_APBPeriphClockConfig(__GPIO7, ENABLE);

   /* Initialize the GPIO port */
   GPIO_DeInit(GPIO7);

   /* Configure port 7 pins as general purpose output */
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Direction = GPIO_PinOutput;
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_All;
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Type = GPIO_Type_PushPull;
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_IPConnected = GPIO_IPConnected_Disable;
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Alternate = GPIO_OutputAlt1;
   GPIO_Init (GPIO7, &GPIO_InitStructure);
}
```

Once the port has been configured, you can use the library function

```
GPIO_Write(...);  /* see documentation for parameters */
```

to write to all 8 bits at once or

```
GPIO_WriteBit(...);  /* see documentation for parameters */
```

to write to a single bit at a time.

Note this is untested code.